# c# linq list one item could have two values based on another item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

My project is MVC5, using EF 6.1, MS Sql.  I am generating a list using:

```
  var data = db.Nutritions
            .Include(nutrition => nutrition.FoodGroup)
            .Include(nutrition => nutrition.Meal)
            .Include(nutrition => nutrition.Fruit)
            .Include(nutrition => nutrition.Vegetable)
            .Select(nutrition =>
             new
             {
                 MealID = nutrition.MealID,
                 MealName = nutrition.Meal.MealName,
                 FoodGroupID = nutrition.FoodGroupID,
                 FoodGroupName = nutrition.FoodGroup.FoodGroupName,
                 FoodTypeID = nutrition.FoodTypeID,
                 FoodName = nutrition.Fruit.Name,
               //FoodName = nutrition.Vegetable.Name
             }).ToList().AsEnumerable();
```

From these tables:
[image]

My challenge is I am trying to get the FoodName, which could come from two tables: Fruits and Vegetables.  The difference is the FoodGroupID in the two table, Fruits FoodGroupID is 1 while Vegetable is 6.  Is there a way to change the FoodName based on the FoodGroupID or should I generate two lists using Where FoodGroupID equals 1 or 6, then combine the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think should also handle if `FoodGroupID` not 1 nor 6:

```
FoodName = nutrition.FoodGroupID == 1 ? nutrition.Fruit.Name : (nutrition.FoodGroupID == 6 ? nutrition.Vegetable.Name : null)
```

Comment: Worked great, thank you.  How to do this in case I have 4 more FoodGroupID.

Comment: @hncl replace `null` with another conditions: `(nutrition.FoodGroupID == 2 ? ... : null)`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
FoodName = nutrition.FoodGroupID == 1 ? nutrition.Fruit.Name : FoodName = nutrition.Vegetable.Name
```

Where `1` is the value for the `FoodGroupID.Fruits` property, If that is wrong replace it with the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
FoodName = nutrition.FoodGroupID == 1 ? nutrition.Fruit.Name : nutrition.Vegetable.Name
```